# Okay to use nil as BOOL for NO?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, null, boolean

I wanted to deselect every visible cell in a UITableView that happens be highlighted. I tried this line of code, and I was amazed that it actually works.

```
[[self.tableView visibleCells]makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setHighlighted:)withObject:nil];
```

So I tried the opposite, to highlight every cell with this:

```
[[self.tableView visibleCells]makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setHighlighted:)withObject:[NSObject new]];
```

And it works to! Is it OK to code like this? To use an object or nil as a substitute for boolean values of YES or NO? Or will it cause any problems?

Comment: Maybe its not the best workaround, but it will do the job.

Comment: The principle question aside, this is how I rewrote the first line of code: `for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) cell.highlighted = NO;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [...] I was amazed that it actually works.

The fact that this works is coincidental. It highly depends on the calling conventions of the architecture and the actual address of the object.

If, for example, `[NSObject new]` would return an object at an address that is aligned to 256 bytes (trailing hex digits 00) it might be interpreted as `NO`.

> Is it OK to code like this?

Definitely not. As I said, it is fragile and might confuse other developers coming after you.

Here's the excerpt from the C standard (regarding calling a function with argument types that do not match the declaration):

> **6.5.2.2 Function calls**
>
> [...]
>
> 9) If the function is defined with a type that is not compatible with the type (of the expression) pointed to by the expression that denotes the called function, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @user3351949 No, that's a different case. In your example the C compiler can see the conversion (of a pointer type to `int`) and automatically does whatever is necessary. While the C Standard says this conversion is "implementation defined", every compiler on earth will do the proper thing here.

Comment: Oh thank you, I just started to afraid :-), woooaaahahh :)